# Is heap allocation more efficient for paging in large blocks?

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc, new-operator, heap-memory

For large (~64k+) allocations, is heap allocation more efficient?

For stack allocation, the pages need to be demand-paged in when used. Do allocators typically do this more efficiently for the heap, for instance mapping virtual memory pages to physical memory in bulk?

Answer (score 0):

As I know always stack is more efficient. But the stack is static, but heap will grow dynamically. So it is better to use the heap for the large memory usage to prevent stack overflow